# Toldot Aharon Tallit

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol, chasidut-hasidism, tallit-katan

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toldot_Aharon), which cites a sefer of takanot by the Toldot Aharon Rebbes, chassidim of that sect do not wear wool, for fear of shaatnez. If this is the case, what material are their tallitot and tzitziot made from?

Comment: IIRC the issue was/is that for "centuries" Yidden used wool from some island (referred to as "Turkey" for historical reasons). That island has no linen industry and therefore the wool was assumed to be Shaatnez-free. Recently (approx 10 years ago?) it was discovered that "Turkey" was keeping up with growing demands for their pure wool by adding in (imported?) linen. See http://www.tallit-shop.com/turkish-tallit-kmo/ who writes: The Turkish tallit is actually not from Turkey, but from Tunisia. During the 19th century, when Tunisia was under Ottoman rule  a sultan banned linen from the country.

Comment: When this thing first broke a chosid told me the historical reason "טורקאי" is Yiddish for "out there somewhere" :)

Comment: Relevant: http://kehuna.org/tzitzit-made-of-shatnez/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are still woolen. Since tallitot and tzitziot are under strict supervision, they are ([wrongly?](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/30841/shatnez-tallis-crisis-growing-concerns-over-shatnez-found-in-talleisim.html)) assumed to be safe.

Source: My uncle, a Toldos Aharon chassid.

Comment: +1 for the "wrongly?". Tallitot from the problematic plants are still available.